# Calling .__module__ return None instead of the package name

Tags: python, opencv

In python, when calling .__module__ with any functions from the cv2 package it returns None. It seems that opencv functions are considered as built-in function.

```py
import cv2
print(cv2.GaussianBlur.__module__)
print(cv2.GaussianBlur)
```

EDIT :

The usecase I have is to keep trace of what function was applied to a dataset. So I use

```py
function.__module__ + '.' + function.__name__
```

Here is a working example using np.sum :

```py
import numpy as np
import importlib

function = np.sum

PATH = function.__module__ + '.' + function.__name__

module = importlib.import_module('.'.join(PATH.split('.')[:-1]))
func = getattr(module, PATH.split('.')[-1])
```

Any tricks to make it work as intended ?

I have opened an issue on the opencv github: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/19349

Comment: The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html) cleaely states that `None` is a valid value for `__module__`.

Comment: @KlausD. Fair point. But I am trying to keep a trace of what function was applied on a dataset.
I am using function.__module__ and function.__name__ to keep a trace of the function that was applied this work well for most usecase, except opencv which return None.

I have edited my question to clarify my issue